# Replacing $$ xyz $$ with \begin{equation} xyz \end{equation} document-wide in overleaf

Tags: math-mode, overleaf

Pretty much the title. I have a latex document where all the centred mathmode texts are written by enclosing them in double dollar signs and I would like to replace them with `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.

Is there an easy way to do this in overleaf using find and replace? Looking up stuff online suggests that regular expressions could do it, but I'm unfamiliar with using them so a detailed 'how-to' would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! While the purpose is commendable, I fear that the question is off-topic here, as it is not really a (La)TeX issue but rather an editor issue.

Comment: With `sed` you could try `sed -i ':a $!{ N; ba }; s/\$\$\([^$]*\)\$\$/\\begin{equation}\1\\end{equation}/g' copy_of_file.tex`. Make a copy of the file and test on *that*!

Comment: Download the file, query-replace every other $$ with begin...in your favorite editor, Then globally replace the remaining $$ with end ... .  Then upload. You could do it in one pass with awk but it might take longer to write the script than this the partly automated method.

Comment: @campa Yeah, I kind of thought this might be off-topic, but I wasn't sure where to ask it and thought this might be the closest stack-exchange group.

Comment: This will result in all your equations being numbered.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 4):

This is only marginally on topic but

Ctrl-F will start the replace dialog then click regex search option at the bottom left of that then search for

```
\$\$([^$]*)\$\$
```

and replace by

```
\begin{equation}$1\end{equation}
```

[image]

this will only do cases where both `$$` are on the same line, I don't think the editor has multi-line regex.

Here `[^$]` means any character that is not a `$` (`[a-z]` means any of the characters a-z for example) `*` means any number of them and the `(..)` form a capture group that is referenced in the replacement by `$1` (other regex editors might use `\1` for this reference in the replacement). So the match captures any string of non-$ characters between pairs of $$.

Alternatively just do a normal non regex replace of `$$` to `\begin{equation}` and alternate yes/no on each then replace all the remaining ones by `\end{equation}`

Comment: @campa you know I did test this:-)  different regex systems differ on the backref syntax, `\1` replaced every formula with literally `\1` (I tried that first:-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked as per my requirements. Just a follow-up question - what does the first regex mean? 
I understand that the \$ indicates the $ signs, but what does ([^$]*) mean? I would venture a guess that the $ here is a placeholder?

Comment: @Afham I added a description to the answer

Comment: Note that this replacement will result in all equations being numbered.  What about `\[...\]` for unnumbered equations?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I want all of my equations to be numbered.